# Key press event is not triggering

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to create a numeric text box control by inheriting edit text control in class library.I'm using Keypress event handler to restrict the user to enter only the numbers using regex.But the Keypress event is not triggering.

My code is

Class library

```
public class NumericTextBox : EditText 
{
    Color backgroundColor = Color.Blue;
    Color textColor = Color.White;
    public NumericTextBox(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        textColor = this.TextColor;
        backgroundColor = this.BackgroundColor;
        KeyPress += new System.EventHandler<View.KeyEventArgs> (NumericTextBox_KeyPress);
    }
    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.backgroundColor;
        }
        set
        {
            this.backgroundColor = value;
        }
    }

    public Color TextColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textColor;
        }
        set
        {
            this.textColor = value;
        }
    }
   public void NumericTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        if(e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)
        {
            if(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(editText.Text,"[0-9]"))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
               Toast.MakeText(this,"enter only numbers",ToastLength.Long).show();
            }
        }
```

MainActivity

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        NumericTextBox onlyNum = new NumericTextBox(BaseContext);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.SetText("Enter only numbers", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        textView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
        NumericTextBox editText = new NumericTextBox(this);
        editText.SetWidth(250);
        editText.SetHeight(100);
        editText.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
        editText.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
        editText.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;
        linearLayout.AddView(textView);
        linearLayout.AddView(editText);
        SetContentView(linearLayout);
    }
```

Numeric TextBox is a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently. It will save you headaches.

I would set the keyboard to numerical `edit.SetInputType(...)` where the parameter is one of these: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Text.InputTypes  Depending on what you want to do setting it to Phone or one of the Number* will work.

Second, I would use a TextFilter to filter input. Here is an example one from here that checks min/max, but you can filter just about any characters: https://dzone.com/articles/xamarinandroid-implementing

```
public class MinMaxInputFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{
     private int _min = 0;
     private int _max = 0;

     public MinMaxInputFilter (int min, int max)
     {
          _min = min;
          _max = max;
     }

     public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(
          Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, 
          int start, 
          int end, 
          ISpanned dest, 
          int dstart, 
          int dend)
     {
          try
          {
               string val = dest.ToString().Insert(dstart, source.ToString());
               int input = int.Parse(val);
               if (IsInRange(_min, _max, input))
                    return null;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               Debug.WriteLine ("FilterFormatted Error: " + ex.Message);
          }

          return new Java.Lang.String (string.Empty);
     }

     private bool IsInRange(int min, int max, int input)
     {
          return max > min ? input >= min && input <= max : input >= max && input     <= min;
     }
}
```

By doing this, you're not letting the user enter anything they shouldn't, which is generally better user experience.